# Print key input [auto hotkey]

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to print out what has been assigned to each combination of the keys "Shift" and "F1-12" when a user displays a help menu. Currently I have been trying to do this by emulating a key press. How do you emulate a key press and print straight to a variable? Or is there a better method of getting what action has been assigned to a set of keys?

Currently I have the following:

```
Loop, 12
{
    msgList =%msgList% (Shift+) F%A_Index%  Send, {Shift}{F1} `n
}
```

Comment: where in the code is the key press emulated?

Comment: I am trying to have it emulate in the message box. Currently when Shift + F1 is pressed "My Name" is automatically typed out.

Comment: Do you know the Hotkey GUI command? https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControls.htm#Hotkey Useful for customized hotkey assignments etc when you have a gui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

too much text for another comment:

The "action" triggered by a hotkey can be **any** combination of commands, like 500 lines of code, possibly with gotos, functions and if-statements.....  how should this be printed out to the user? The closest thing to this would be printing the entire source code.

If you want to only change the keys which are sent by `Send` (here: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, you could maybe store them in a variable and access it dynamically. something like this

```
shiftF1 = {Shift}{F1}
shiftF2 = {Shift}{F2}

+F1::send %shiftF1%
+F2::send %shiftF2%
```

Then, you'd be able to edit `shiftF1` and print it out to the user